# Admob Android getting onAdFailedToLoad ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL but did not change anything

Tags: admob

When I compile my app I always get onAdFailedToLoad with ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL which means that currently Admob has no ads to provide. This never happened in two years and if I try the current version from play store then it shows ads properly!

- If I add my device as a test device it shows the test ads properly
- If I compile an old version of my app then I also get ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL. But this old version worked fine showing ads in the past and there is no change in AdMob configuration or in this version!

I read many posts on stackoverflow but I do not have "Designed for families" active, lack of privacy policy. I have no changed anything!?

Anyone else having this issue with AdMob?

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':SliderPreference')
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MobileAds.initialize(context, BuildConfig.AD_APP_ID);
    MobileAds.setAppMuted(true);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.AD_UNIT_ID);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Log.d("AD", "onAdFailedToLoad: "+String.valueOf(errorCode));
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d("AD", "onAdLoaded: ");
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            if (!mAppSettings.isUnlocked(mAppSettings.PRODUCT_NOADS.productId,Tools.getSettings(context))) {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
            promotionAndAdsFinished();
        }
    });
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()             
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads):

> Caution: If you set up an app-ads.txt file for your app, you need to also include this line in your app-ads.txt file in order to load ads using the demo ad units:
>
> google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
>
> Alternatively, you can enable test devices and use your own ad unit IDs instead.

Comment: It will take some time for the changes of the app-ads.txt file to take effect